# Enter to submit form

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble adding code to be able to submit form by clicking Enter. I have tried a few things, but I simply cannot make it work.

I'm quite new, so that might be why.

Thank you guys in advance.

```
<div class="box">
    <h1>Foretag et opkald via Remote Control</h1>
    <input type="number" id="dial">
    <a id="call" href="" target-"null">Start opkald til <span id="tel"></span>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $('#dial').on('input', function() {
        $('#tel').html($(this).val())
        $('#call').attr("href", "http://192.168.6.91/servlet?key=number=" + $(this).val() + "&outgoing_uri=9081@213.128.137.88")
        console.log($(this).val()) // get the current value of the input field.
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please explain more clearly. what issue you are facing

Comment: @Vishalmodi - I'm just too stupid to make it work. Not sure where to start; I can't figure out what to do :)

Comment: Use a form, the default behaviour is to submit when a control is focused and enter is pressed. No code required. You will also find the controls far more accessible, again with zero script required.

Comment: Please describe your problem and what you want as output it's good for perfect answer

Comment: Paste this URL in your browser: `data:text/html,<input type="number" onchange='window.location.href="http://192.168.6.91/servlet?key=number=" + this.value+ "&outgoing_uri=9081@213.128.137.88"'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform any activity like form submittion based on enter pressed on textbox, you can track it by `keycode` in `keyup` event.

```html
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Foretag et opkald via Remote Control</h1>
    <input type="number" id="dial">
    <a id="call" href="" target-"null">Start opkald til <span id="tel"></span>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $('#dial').on('keyup', function() {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
   
   
        $('#tel').html($(this).val())
        $('#call').attr("href", "http://192.168.6.91/servlet?key=number=" + $(this).val() + "&outgoing_uri=9081@213.128.137.88")
        console.log($(this).val()) // get the current value of the input field.
      
        if(keycode == '13'){
         //form submit
         $('#call')[0].click();
         }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have given that a shot – however when doing that, the browser pops up with a "This page says: "

And the command isn't executed on the device.

Comment: it is just for demo, instead of that alert you can add your code.

Comment: you are beginner, so you will face such kind of issue, it means not that you are dump. so instead of  get irritated focus on learning.
hope above answer resolved your query.

Comment: Alright, so .. The snippet you've sent has been added to my code. You previously stated, that I had to add my code instead of the alert. I hate asking for the "answer", as I'd like to learn it for myself, however, I feel like in this state, getting the answer - and understanding it, would help me a ton.

Are you able to help me with that? I know people hate when you ask for the answer.

If I'm lucky enough, here's the entire code: https://hastebin.com/vezobosire.xml

Thanks Vishal :)

Comment: I can not understand, what really you want. I have already served you what you want. so what is your exactly question? please be clear.

Comment: With the above code I sent, the script isn't executed.

This script >previously< executed a remote call on an IP phone by using the

```
$('#call').attr("href", "http://192.168.6.91/servlet?key=number=" + $(this).val() + "&outgoing_uri=9081@213.128.137.88")
``` 

Code – however, now, it doesn't execute, but instead alerts an empty command (without executing the script)

Comment: Hmm, still issue arrives – doesn't execute the script. The alert properly pops up, but the actual script is never executed regardless of the alert going through.

Comment: every time when you are entering data, you can see values in console, so how can you say code not executing.

Comment: When entering the specified number to dial, and I use the "Start opkald til" > "Start call to" button, it forwards me to the page which then executes the script, this page is: http://192.168.6.91/servlet?key=number=, which by using + $(this).val() adds the end of the URL, which is: "&outgoing_uri=9081@213.128.137.88".

This works when using the button to start the call, however, when using Enter, it doesn't redirect to the specified page (which the button does).

Sorry for being a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

In pure HTML:

```html
<form>
  <input id="myinput"/>
  <button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('myinput').value)">Send</button>
</form>
```

A `button` inside a `form` will automatically be triggered whenever enter is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
 <div class="box">
    <h1>Foretag et opkald via Remote Control</h1>
    <input type="number" id="dial">
    <a id="call" href="" target-"null">Start opkald til <span id="tel"></span>
</div>
```

Try this:

```
 <from id="#formId">
    <h1>Foretag et opkald via Remote Control</h1>
    <input type="number" id="dial">
    <input type="submit" value="Enter">
</from>
```

To submit the form:

```
  $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
        // prevent Default functionality
        e.preventDefault();

      // get the input values from the from
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your input in a form, it will submit on <kbd>enter</kbd> key by default.

Here's an example of how to use this:

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const children = e.target.children;
  for (child of children) {
    if (child.type !== "submit") {
      console.log(child.value); // do something here
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text"/>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It iterates over elements in a form and does *something* with each non-submit element. Note that pressing enter in a textarea will just create a new line.